# MySQL Query, Count issue

Tags: mysql, count

THANKS EVERYONE - SOLVED!

I have the following code:

```
SELECT region, division, SUM(staff_count) AS Total_Staff, 
(SELECT COUNT(region) FROM tresults_xyc WHERE division = 'Central' GROUP BY region) AS Total_Responses
FROM  `trespondent_xyc` 
WHERE division = 'Central'
GROUP BY region
```

It brings back the following:

```
region  division    Total_Staff Total_Responses
1       Central     212         8
2       Central     168         8
3       Central     164         8
4       Central     180         8
```

The information contained in the colomns region, division, and Total_Staff are correct.

However, the Total_Responses colomn is not - that is showing the total number of responses for the Division and not each region.

Can anyone advise?

Thanks in advance,

Homer.

Comment: Your inner query has no any reference to region thus counts values for all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do this :

```
SELECT region, division, SUM(staff_count) AS Total_Staff, 
       (
           SELECT COUNT(*) 
           FROM tresults_xyc t2
           WHERE t2.region = t1.region
       ) AS Total_Responses
FROM  `trespondent_xyc` t1
WHERE division = 'Central'
GROUP BY region
```

Comment: The second query will produce different results

Comment: Indeed, the first query worked perfectly.  The second produced spurious results!

Answer (score 0):

try

```
SELECT region, division, SUM(staff_count) AS Total_Staff, (SELECT COUNT(region) FROM tresults_xyc WHERE division = 'Central' and region = xx.region GROUP BY region) AS Total_Responses
FROM  `trespondent_xyc` xx 
WHERE division = 'Central'
GROUP BY region
```

Comment: Works, except it brings back NULLS, the code before (first query) brings me back zeros where there are no responses.